# what should strlen() really return in this code?

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char qq[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'};
    char qqq[] = "abcd";
    printf("%d\n" , sizeof qq / sizeof qq[0]); // line A
    printf("%d\n" , strlen(qq)); // line B
    printf("%d\n" , sizeof qqq / sizeof qqq[0]); // line C
    printf("%d\n" , strlen(qqq)); // line D

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Look at the code above. The array `qq` has four elements in it and the array `qqq` has five elements in it the last of which is `'\0'`. So I understand line A prints `4` and line C prints `5`. Line D is OK with me. I understand that `strlen(qqq)` equals `"sizeof qqq / sizeof qqq[0] - 1"` when dealing with strings. But Line B prints `15` which makes me puzzled. Why? (I use vs2012.)

Comment: Note: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` format specifier.

Comment: same thing for sizeof operator use s%zu instead of %d or %ld becouse of long unsigned int

Comment: It might print anything. `strlen()` will happily just keep moving through memory until it finds a 0. It just happened to find one 15 bytes in.

Answer (score 8):

In your code

```
  char qq[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'};
```

`qq` is not qualified to be called a *string*, as it is not null-terminated. So calling `strlen()` wilh `qq` is inviting trouble.

What actually happens here is, `strlen()` goes past the last valid element in `qq` in search of terminating null (which is actually missing), and thus, venture into out-of-bound memory, which invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: To make `qq` a *string*, you have to add the null-terminator in the initializer list yourself, like

```
 char qq[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd', '\0'};
```

That said, as I already mentioned in my comment, as [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) return type is `size_t`, you should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

---

Just in a lighter mood, to answer

> *what should strlen() really return in this code?*

If I say, *"The phone number of the Respected President of India"*, well, technically, I *might be* correct !!

On a serious note, the output of UB in, well, undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Your string is not null-terminated. That means your code is not deterministic. `strlen()` will terminate whenever it encounters a `\0` (null byte/character); the result can vary due to it sequential scanning until the `\0` is encountered.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` computes length of string but `char qq[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd'};` is not string. Undefined results are obtained when `'Non-String'` data is passed to `strlen`.

Strings are `null terminated` in `c`.

It should be `char qq[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd','\0'};`

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` will work its way forward until it finds a `\0` character, counting how many characters there are along the way.

Because `qq` does not have a `\0` in it, `strlen` will ***keep going*** into other, unrelated memory.   Eventually, by chance, it encounters a `\0` byte.

Apparently for you that is after 15 bytes (or 11 bytes beyond the end of `qq`).
**But it is not deterministic or guaranteed, and is very unsafe.**
   It is very possible that `strlen` will end up trying to read invalid memory before it happens to find a `\0` character, in which case your program will seg-fault.